# who is setting getDefaultNightMode()

Tags: android, android-night-mode

I would like to add Night/Day theme to my app, and I read a lot of articles online, but I still don't understand who is setting this method, is it the Android OS, or do I have to create a method based on season and time of day to setDefaultNightMode()?

Answer (score 0):

You application theme is handled by you, the operative system and SystemUI colors are handled by the system.

To change theme in your application you have to define your style in `res/values/styles.xml` as below, and you have apply it in your activity code (before the `setContentView()` method)

```
<style name="AppLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appColorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/appColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/appColorAccentLight</item>
</style>


<style name="AppDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/appColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/appColorAccentDark</item>
</style>
```

And in your main activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Here goes the theme setup
    setTheme(R.style.AppDark)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

You can obviously change the algorithm to apply light/dark theme basing on your app logics.
About android night more implementation, every OEM has a custom implementation of android operative sytstem, some devices has a built-in theme manager and other ones does not allow theming at all, thus an universal theming features it not present yet